# SQL Management Studio - Add-on / Extension to view Column Data Type

Tags: sql-server, ssms, plugins

Is there any way (built in) or free/paid add-on/Extension for SQL Management Studio that allows us to know exactly a data type of a column when we are writing a query?

In this specific project I have had situations where by looking a the query result I am not exactly sure of the datatype, if it is a number written in a nvarchar(max) column.... or if it is a tinyint, or int, or bigint, etc....

And I am spending so much time just to drill on the "tree list" to reach a speficic table and expand the Columns node to find out what am I dealing with....

A situation when you have bunch of JOINS (and allias) and `sp_help <tablename>` would require me always to go to some other query window and type more sql (table names)....  then it would be **easier and faster just to have like a tooltip message of the column with extra info.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard functionality of SSMS (and has been for a while, I tested in both SSMS 2014 and SSMS 17.2).

For example when you hover over a column the tooltip shows you the data type:

[image]

The intellisense autocomplete also shows the data type when you select a column with your up/down arrows:

[image]

Comment: Well, that is funny, because my SSMS is not showing  anything similar to your results :( But if you tell me that is a default functionality, then I will try to install it again or a newer version and try again... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I tested in both SSMS 2014 and SSMS 17.2